# VBA Excel Validation list over Variable Range

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation

I tried this code to set a validation list in Excel. I'm trying to substitute specific cells with variables, but I can't make it work out with fixed cells.

Thank you.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Range(Cells(5, 15), Cells(6, 15))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= "=" & Range(Cells(5, 15), Cells(6, 15)).Address
```

or this:

```
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= "=$O$5:$O$6"
```